# How to connect to localhost from a docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a Python application to expose a REST API. The Python server is running on  `http://127.0.0.1:5000`
I have another application written in NodeJS to wrap the API coming from Python and expose another API as a passthrough. The Node server is running on `http://localhost:8080`

I'm new to Docker, I'm building a docker image for the Node application (in MacOS Silicon). **The problem is when I invoke the API using `curl http://localhost:8080` The docker desktop says "Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:5000"**

The following is the docker run command I'm using

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 -d -v ./Config.toml -p 8080:8080 myApp/app:v0.1.0
```

I tried with the `--network host` flag with the `docker run` command, but it doesn't work since it ignores all the declared ports. And I tried with the `http.server --bind 0.0.0.0` with the `docker run` command, but the result says "pull access denied for http.server"

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: @Zeitounator I'm not sure, the linked question is something similar to MySQL which is not my case

Comment: This is an automatic comment generated because I linked a duplicate. It answers your question which is how to connect to a service running on your host from one running inside a docker container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl http://127.0.0.1:5000` on host machine to see if server is actually running.

Check server accessibility from within container. Simply run the docker container on interactive `it` and try access the server from the container.

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 -it myApp/app:v0.1.0 /bin/bash
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

If this does not work, it's a network configuration issue in the container you should set up to allow access to host machine.

If it works, then bind NodeJs app to  0.0.0.0 to allow conns from any ip.

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 -d -v ./Config.toml -p 8080:8080 myApp/app:v0.1.0 -host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: It's not working for me, but trying with `-it` is something I missed here. So I accept this answer